# In Jquery UI Date Picker, showing selected date in header while moving the "changeMonth" and "changeYear" below the header

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, font-awesome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/blL1q.png

So basically this is the design UI i want for the Datepicker. Is it even possible to redesign the arrow using font-icons(font-awesome) and attaching bootstraps for the dropdowns

Comment: ok thanks, but how do you show selected date in header then move the “changeMonth” and “changeYear” dropdowns below the header just like in the image?

Comment: Can you post a sample code so that I can understand more clearly?